# Unable to save file in folder using python open()

Tags: python, save

My English is very poor, and the use of the Google translation, I am sorry for that. :)

Unable to save filename, error indicating no directory exists, but directory exists.

1.You can manually create the file in the resource manager --> the file name is legal.

2.You can manually create a directory in the resource manager --> the directory name is legal

3.You can save other file names such as aaa.png to this directory, that is, this directory can be written to other files --> The path path is legal, there is no permission problem, and there is no problem with the writing method.

4.The file can be written to the upper-level directory download_pictures --> It's not a file name problem.

thank you!!!

```py
import os

path = 'download_pictures\\landscape[or]no people[or]nature[OrderBydata]\\'
download_name = '[6]772803-2500x1459-genshin+impact-lumine+(genshin+impact)-arama+(genshin+impact)-aranara+(genshin+impact)-arabalika+(genshin+impact)-arakavi+(genshin+impact).png'
filename = path + download_name
print('filename = ', filename)

# Create the folder make sure the path exists
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

try:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('test')
except Exception as e:
    print('\n【error!】First save file, failed, caught exception：', e)
    print(filename)

filename = path + 'aaa.png'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    print('\nThe second save file, changed the file name aaa.png, the path remains unchanged')
    f.write('test')
    print(filename)

path = 'download_pictures\\'
filename = path + download_name
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    print('\nThe third save file, the file name is unchanged, but the directory has changed')
    f.write('test')
```

console

```
filename =  download_pictures\landscape[or]no people[or]nature[OrderBydata]\[6]772803-2500x1459-genshin+impact-lumine+(genshin+impact)-arama+(genshin+impact)-aranara+(genshin+impact)-arabalika+(genshin+impact)-arakavi+(genshin+impact).png

【error!】First save file, failed, caught exception： [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'download_pictures\\landscape[or]no people[or]nature[OrderBydata]\\[6]772803-2500x1459-genshin+impact-lumine+(genshin+impact)-arama+(genshin+impact)-aranara+(genshin+impact)-arabalika+(genshin+impact)-arakavi+(genshin+impact).png'
download_pictures\landscape[or]no people[or]nature[OrderBydata]\[6]772803-2500x1459-genshin+impact-lumine+(genshin+impact)-arama+(genshin+impact)-aranara+(genshin+impact)-arabalika+(genshin+impact)-arakavi+(genshin+impact).png

The second save file, changed the file name aaa.png, the path remains unchanged
download_pictures\landscape[or]no people[or]nature[OrderBydata]\aaa.png

The third save file, the file name is unchanged, but the directory has changed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please provide the error itself, so it's clear what's the problem. So far I don't understand where you encounter an issue.

Comment: thanks,Cannot save the specified file.console：[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'download_pictures\\landscape[or]no people[or]nature[OrderBydata]\\[6]772803-2500x1459-genshin+impact-lumine+(genshin+impact)-arama+(genshin+impact)-aranara+(genshin+impact)-arabalika+(genshin+impact)-arakavi+(genshin+impact).png'
download_pictures\landscape[or]no people[or]nature[OrderBydata]\[6]772803-2500x1459-genshin+impact-lumine+(genshin+impact)-arama+(genshin+impact)-aranara+(genshin+impact)-arabalika+(genshin+impact)-arakavi+(genshin+impact).png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't replicate your error (I'm using linux and I think you have a Windows system), but anyway, you should not try to join paths manually. Instead try to use `os.path.join` to join multiple paths to one valid path. This will also ensure that based on your operating system the correct path separators are used (forward slash on unix and backslash on Windows).

I have adapted the code until the first saving attempt accordingly and it writes a file correctly. Also, the code gets cleaner this way and it's easier to see the separate folder names.

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = os.path.join('download_pictures', 'landscape[or]no people[or]nature[OrderBydata]')
    download_name = '[6]772803-2500x1459-genshin+impact-lumine+(genshin+impact)-arama+(genshin+impact)-aranara+(genshin+impact)-arabalika+(genshin+impact)-arakavi+(genshin+impact).png'
    filename = os.path.join(path, download_name)
    print('filename = ', filename)

    # Create the folder make sure the path exists
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    try:
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write('test')
    except Exception as e:
        print('\n【error!】First save file, failed, caught exception：', e)
        print(filename)
```

I hope this helps. I think the issue with your approach is related to the path separators `\\` under Windows.